# How to choose between block_in_place and spawn_blocking?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I'm working a lot with tokio and I've been using [spawn_blocking](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/fn.spawn_blocking.html) for code that is going to block the thread. Then I saw the documentation for [block_in_place](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/fn.block_in_place.html) and it seems like it's an unrestricted (Send, 'static) version of the former.

My question is, if I'm already on a threaded runtime, when is using block_in_place not advisable? What are the differences and advantages of each method of driving sync code? Can it be a problem if I block_in_place a lot, for example, in all my threads at the same time? How does it work?

I read all of the tokio documentation and didn't find the answer to these questions, so it felt right to ask here.

Comment: You should generally use spawn_blocking if you can. Use block_in_place if spawn_blocking can't work.

Answer (score 3):

If you can use `spawn_blocking`, use it.

`block_in_place` is less restrictive in that it does not require its argument to have `'static` lifetime, but has two disadvantages. First, it makes executor perform additional work to move other tasks off the thread. Second, it prevents running other futures on the same task, which means it is pointless to [join](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/future/struct.Join.html) `block_in_place` future with other futures.

> Can it be a problem if I block_in_place a lot, for example, in all my threads at the same time? How does it work?

You can read [the implementation of `block_in_place`](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio/blob/52da177dea169aa9f3dac6b1465fa5229a9615bb/tokio/src/runtime/scheduler/multi_thread/worker.rs#L252)

It is not a problem to use `block_in_place` a lot except for additional overhead. It [calls `spawn_blocking` internally prior to executing the function passed inside](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio/blob/52da177dea169aa9f3dac6b1465fa5229a9615bb/tokio/src/runtime/scheduler/multi_thread/worker.rs#L343)